# SharePoint Foundation 2010 - Automatically add the parent folder name to a column

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, document-library

Is there a way to automatically add the name of the parent folder to a column in which the documents are stored?

I have a SharePoint 2010 Foundation environment with a document library named IT. In this IT document library, I have several folders containing procedures and howto's. Separate permissions have been configured on the folders.

```
-Windows 7
-- Users
-- Administrators
- Windows 8
-- Users
-- Administrators
- Windows XP
-- Users
-- Administrators
```

[image: IT: All documents]
[image: IT: Windows 7]

Users access the document library using a view where the option "show items without folders" has been enabled. Because of the permissions, they don't see folders they don't have access to.

I tried making a workflow with one step that starts automatically when an item is created or changed:

*"Set Parent Folder to Current Item:Path"*
[image: Workflow step]

When the workflow is done, the path is shown as "/IT/Windows 7/Administrators". But I only need the last part "Administrators" instead of the entire path:

[image: Path]

How can I get only the last folder name from the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lectori salutem,

I solved this question by installing a third party addon "Advanced Workflow Actions for SharePoint Designer 2010" by [iLove SharePoint](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/)

URL: http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Get%20Parent%20Folder%20Action

This addon adds extra actions for workflows in SharePoint Designer.